# How to expect a specific word after a route parameter in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Currently I have this route:

```
router.get('/:board/:threadId', function(req, res, next) {
    // doing stuff
});
```

So the users go to `/a/1` and it triggers this route with `board = a` and `threadId = 1`.

What I want now is that the users need to go to `/a/1.html` to trigger this route (but `threadId` should still equal `1`. How do I add the `.html` in that route? I tried `/:board/:threadId.*.html$` after reading the [express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-paths) but it's not working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hyphen (-) and the dot (.) are interpreted literally by string-based paths.

Did you try this?

```
router.get('/:board/:threadId.html', function(req, res, next) {
    // doing stuff
});
```